# Select sample from a grouping variable depending on another grouping in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame with 1,000 rows; 10 Cities, each having 100 rows and I would like to randomly select 10 names by Year in the city and the selected should 10 sample names should come from at least one of the years in the City i.e the 10 names for City 1 should not come from only 1996 for instance.

```
       City Year   name   
1       1   1996   b
2       1   1996   c
3       1   1997   d
4       1   1997   e 
...
101     2   1996   f
102     2   1996   g
103     2   1997   h
104     2   1997   i
```

Desired Final Sample Data

```
       City Year   name   
1       1   1996   b
2       1   1998   c
3       1   2001   d
...
11      2   1997   g
12      2   1999   h
13      2   2005   b
...
21      3   1998   a
22      3   2010   c
23      3   2005   d
```

Sample Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(City = rep(1:10, each = 100), 
                  Year = rep(1996:2015, each = 5), 
                  name = rep(letters[1:25], 40))
```

I am failing to randomly select the 10 sample names by Year (without repeating years - unless when the number of Years in a city is less than 10) for all the 10 Cities, how can I go over this?

The Final sample should have 10 names of each city and years should not repeat unless when they are less than 10 in that city.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group by `City` and use `sample_n` to sample a sub-dataframe.
Then group by `City` and `Year`, and `sample` from `name` one element per group. Don't forget to set the RNG seed in order to make the result reproducible.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2020)

df1 %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  sample_n(min(n(), 10)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(City, Year) %>%
  summarise(name = sample(name, 1))
#`summarise()` regrouping output by 'City' (override with `.groups` argument)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   City [2]
#   City  Year name 
#  <int> <int> <chr>
#1     1  1996 b    
#2     1  1997 e    
#3     2  1996 f    
#4     2  1997 h
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
       City Year   name   
1       1   1996   b
2       1   1996   c
3       1   1997   d
4       1   1997   e 
101     2   1996   f
102     2   1996   g
103     2   1997   h
104     2   1997   i
", header = TRUE)
```

---

## Edit

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use package `sampling`, function `strata` to get an index into the data set and then `filter` its corresponding rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sampling)

set.seed(2020)

df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  filter(row %in% strata(df1, stratanames = c('City', 'Year'), size = rep(1, 1000), method = 'srswor')$ID_unit) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  sample_n(10) %>%
  arrange(City, Year)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rui. However, this actually prints one year for all the years under a City so if I have 20 years in City 1, it will result in 20 rows for each of those years instead of the maximum 10 samples that should come from City 1. How can that be rectified?

Comment: @SamuelOnyango Done, see now.

Comment: Hi @Rui, it still does not do it. The sample_n line leaves you with 10 rows for each district and the summarise line will reduce it further depending on how many duplicate years you had previously picked from the sample_n. I have also updated the question to include sample data for to see it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @SamuelOnyango See if the new code is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Rui, I will surely go with this as the answer. I end up with the desired data point. However, I am just curious about the filter line, it leaves each city with the unique 20 Years which kind of reduces the rows of each from 100  to 20 where it picks the 10 from.

Comment: @SamuelOnyango Yes, `strata` samples one row per `Year` because this variable is a stratum. So it outputs 20 rows per `City`.